# MySQL Multiple WHERE clauses to same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of users where all information is in a 1-to-1 relationship...

```
    users table

    ------------------------
    id        |   name
    ------------------------
    800       |  Bob Smith
    801       |  Jane Doe
    802       |  Fred Flintstone
    803       |  Barney Rubble
    804       |  Marge Simpson
```

I also have another many-to-1 relationship table which houses the usergroup mapping of all users to the group(s) that they are part of

```
    user_usergroup_map table

    ------------------------
    user_id   |   group_id
    ------------------------
    800       |  16
    800       |  27
    801       |  25
    801       |  27
    802       |  17
    802       |  19
    802       |  22
    802       |  25
    803       |  25
    803       |  27
    804       |  15
```

I am trying to generate an array of distinct users that are part of 2 distinct groups. At the same time, I am trying to keep this all within a single array (for which I will be using as a pagination reference).

I have been able to successfully query both tables via a JOIN statement...

```
    $group_id1 = 25;
    $group_id2 = 27;

    $query = SELECT DISTINCT name, id FROM users INNER JOIN user_usergroup_map on user_usergroup_map.user_id=users.id WHERE group_id IN('$group_id1', '$group_id2');
```

However, with this, I get a distinct list of users who are part of EITHER group_id 15 or group_id 27, instead of those who are part of both groups. I know that I've been staring at this for far too long, and I'm missing some simplistic logical element, but I just can't see it, for the life of me. If anyone out there could shed some light on what I'm probably doing wrong, I'd GREATLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a constraint on `user_usergroup_map` table such that a given user cannot be assigned to the same `group_id` twice, you can do something like this:

```
Select ...
From users
Where id In (
            Select user_id
            From user_usergroup_map
            Where group_id In(25,27)
            Group By user_id
            Having Count(*) = 2
            )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! On top of it all, this also allows for a more simplistic, scalable ordering system. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I think the best approach is using aggregation with a `having` clause, because this is the most general approach.

In your case, the query looks like:

```
select u.name, u.id
from users u join
     user_usergroups_map ug
     on ud.user_id = u.id
group by u.name, u.id
having sum(case when ug.group_id = $group_id1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has group1
       sum(case when ug.group_id = $group_id2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0     -- has group2
```

If you want to limit it to *only* these two groups and nothing else, you can add the following clause:

```
       count(distinct ug.group_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty with MySQL, but something like this should work as well

```
select id, name, count(*) as cnt
from users, user_usergroup_map
where id = user_id
group by user_id
having cnt = 2;
```

It looks nice (to me), but it might be too hard on the server if your tables are large.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u join 
user_usergroup_map g
on u.id = g.user_id
group by u.id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This will give you all the user info that has 2 records in your group map table.